# Checking types in C++11 #defines

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I want to make pre-processor defines based on the value of a `typedef`.

The idea is to check `index_type_t` and generate the appropriate `INDEX_TYPE_GL` define.

The following does not work as intended.

```
typedef uint32_t index_type_t;

#ifdef INDEX_TYPE_GL
#undef INDEX_TYPE_GL
#endif

#if (index_type_t == uint8_t)
#define INDEX_TYPE_GL   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
#elif (index_type_t == uint32_t)
#define INDEX_TYPE_GL   GL_UNSIGNED_INT
#elif (index_type_t == uint16_t)
#deine INDEX_TYPE_GL    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT
#endif
```

Note that `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` are separate `typdefs` elsewhere and that `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` etc. are integral values, not types.

Comment: Not exactly, the values `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` etc. are integers.

Comment: you can't use #ifs this way , because the preprocessor isn't aware of typedefs, or any other C++ construct for that matter. What you _can_ do is have a typedef or a const value depend on the actual type of index_type_t.

Comment: How might I go about that?

Comment: Jarod42 just answered that :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

enum style:

```
template<typename T> struct IndexTypeGL {};
template<> struct IndexTypeGL<uint8_t>  { enum {value = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE }; };
template<> struct IndexTypeGL<uint16_t> { enum {value = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT}; };
template<> struct IndexTypeGL<uint32_t> { enum {value = GL_UNSIGNED_INT  }; };

#define INDEX_TYPE_GL  IndexTypeGL<index_type_t>::value
```

"static constexpr" style

```
template<typename T> struct IndexTypeGL {};
template<> struct IndexTypeGL<uint8_t>  { static constexpr int value = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE; };
template<> struct IndexTypeGL<uint16_t> { static constexpr int value = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT;};
template<> struct IndexTypeGL<uint32_t> { static constexpr int value = GL_UNSIGNED_INT;  };
```

Comment: Stroke of genius, thank you! :D

Comment: prefer `static const` to the enum hack

Comment: @Manu343726: static constexpr is better than static const. The winner between enum vs const doesn't seem clear.

Comment: @Manu343726 can you give an example of the solution using `static const`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I always forget `constexpr` :) Thanks. Indeed you can think my answer is a suggestion to update the style from C++98 to C++03, instead of C++03 to C++11... But its true, nowadays the best option is `static constexpr`.

Comment: @cmbasnett `template<> struct IndexTypeGL<uint8_t> { static constexpr value = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE; };`

Comment: Turns out that using `static const` is preferable to using `enum` as `enum`s default to 32-bit integers, whereas a static const variable can be 64-bit.

I discovered this when making a templated FNV1 hash function, where the parameters needed to be 64-bit integers.

Comment: _"`enum`s default to 32-bit integers"_ That's not really true. At best it's a gross over-simplification and over-generalisation.